# How to put for loop print in quotations?

Tags: python

So I was provided a doctest and a simple task and completed it, but am unable to figure out how to get the results wrapped in quotation marks as shown in the doctests.

Here's the code:

```
def get_ords(s):
    """
    >>> get_ords('abc')
    '97 98 99 '
    >>> get_ords('a b c')
    '97 32 98 32 99 '
    >>> get_ords('a1 b2 c3')
    '97 49 32 98 50 32 99 51 '
    >>> get_ords('[(!)]')
    '91 40 33 41 93 '
    """
    for ch in s:
        print(ord(ch), end=" ")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod(verbose=True)
```

which outputs the following:

```
Expected:
    '97 98 99 '
Got:
    97 98 99 

Expected:
    '97 32 98 32 99 '
Got:
    97 32 98 32 99 

Expected:
    '97 49 32 98 50 32 99 51 '
Got:
    97 49 32 98 50 32 99 51 

Expected:
    '91 40 33 41 93 '
Got:
    91 40 33 41 93
```

I can't figure out how to wrap the output in quotations within the for loop or whatever. Any help?

Comment: try using r notation, like print r"'1 2 3'"

Comment: Your function is probably meant to `return` a string, not to `print` it. If that's the case, then you don't need to add the quotes yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def get_ords(s):
    """
    >>> get_ords('abc')
    '97 98 99 '
    >>> get_ords('a b c')
    '97 32 98 32 99 '
    >>> get_ords('a1 b2 c3')
    '97 49 32 98 50 32 99 51 '
    >>> get_ords('[(!)]')
    '91 40 33 41 93 '
    """
    r = []
    for ch in list(s):
        r.append(str(ord(ch)))
    print(r)
    return ' '.join(r)

print(get_ords('abc'))
```

output

```
'97 98 99'
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to extra output the quotations, but escaped. Just like:

```py
sys.stdout.write("\'")
for ch in s:
    print(ord(ch), end=" ")
sys.stdout.write("\'")
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my simple way:

```
s = "YOUR_STRING"
print(s)
>>>YOUR_STRING
print('"%s"' %s)
>>>"YOUR_STRING"
```